# How to show zero in the place of no data in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query where i am doing union of some results.Now the query works like, there are 6 rows by default.Now the union will give 6 results against those row.So if all unions have data then no problem,i am getting 6 rows,but the problem is if any of those union don't have data to show then i am not getting 6 rows ,instead i get 4 rows or sometimes 2 .But i want that which query will not have data it will  return 0 there.I am posting my query

```
select count(distinct CANDYS.candidateId) from
(Select C.candidateID,J.joborderID from db_candidatenote C, db_jobordernote   J 
where C.noteid=J.noteid and C.action like 'Engaged' 
and C.dateadded between '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-30' ) N,
(Select distinct Note.candidateId, JNote.jobOrderID 
from db_candidatenote Note,db_jobordernote JNote, corporateuser User where 
Note.noteid=JNote.noteid
and Note.commentingPersonID = User.userid 
and User.firstName='Avishek'
and Note.action='Sourcing') CANDYS
where N.candidateID= CANDYS.candidateId
and N.joborderid=CANDYS.jobOrderID

union

 select count(distinct CANDYS.candidateId) from
(Select C.candidateID,J.joborderID from db_candidatenote C, db_jobordernote J 
 where C.noteid=J.noteid and C.action like 'Qualification' 
and C.dateadded between '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-30' ) N,
(Select distinct Note.candidateId, JNote.jobOrderID 
from db_candidatenote Note,db_jobordernote JNote, corporateuser User where 
Note.noteid=JNote.noteid
and Note.commentingPersonID = User.userid 
and User.firstName='Avishek'
and Note.action='Sourcing') CANDYS
where N.candidateID= CANDYS.candidateId
and N.joborderid=CANDYS.jobOrderID

union

select count(distinct CANDYS.candidateId) from
(Select C.candidateID,J.joborderID from db_candidatenote C, db_jobordernote J 
where C.noteid=J.noteid and C.action like 'Internal Submission' 
and C.dateadded between '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-30' ) N,
(Select distinct Note.candidateId, JNote.jobOrderID 
from db_candidatenote Note,db_jobordernote JNote, corporateuser User where 
Note.noteid=JNote.noteid
and Note.commentingPersonID = User.userid 
and User.firstName='Avishek'
and Note.action='Sourcing') CANDYS
where N.candidateID= CANDYS.candidateId
and N.joborderid=CANDYS.jobOrderID

union

select count(distinct CANDYS.candidateId) from sendout S,
(Select distinct Note.candidateId, JNote.jobOrderID 
from db_candidatenote Note,db_jobordernote JNote, corporateuser User where 
Note.noteid=JNote.noteid
and Note.commentingPersonID = User.userid 
and User.firstName='Avishek'
and Note.action='Sourcing' ) CANDYS
where S.candidateID= CANDYS.candidateId
and S.joborderid=CANDYS.jobOrderID
and S.dateadded between '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-30'

union

  select count(distinct CANDYS.candidateId) from
 (Select C.candidateID,J.joborderID from db_candidatenote C, db_jobordernote J 
  where C.noteid=J.noteid and C.action like '%Interview%' 
  and C.dateadded between '2014-04-01' and '2014-05-30' ) N,
 (Select distinct Note.candidateId, JNote.jobOrderID 
 from db_candidatenote Note,db_jobordernote JNote, corporateuser User where 
 Note.noteid=JNote.noteid
 and Note.commentingPersonID = User.userid 
 and User.firstName='Avishek'
 and Note.action='Sourcing') CANDYS
 where N.candidateID= CANDYS.candidateId
 and N.joborderid=CANDYS.jobOrderID

 union

select count(distinct CANDYS.candidateId) from
(Select C.candidateID,J.joborderID from db_candidatenote C, db_jobordernote J 
where C.noteid=J.noteid and C.action like 'Support' 
and C.dateadded between '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-30' ) N,
(Select distinct Note.candidateId, JNote.jobOrderID 
from db_candidatenote Note,db_jobordernote JNote, corporateuser User where 
Note.noteid=JNote.noteid
and Note.commentingPersonID = User.userid 
and User.firstName='Avishek'
and Note.action='Sourcing') CANDYS
where N.candidateID= CANDYS.candidateId
and N.joborderid=CANDYS.jobOrderID

union

select count(distinct CANDYS.candidateId )from placement P,(Select distinct      Note.candidateId, JNote.jobOrderID 
from db_candidatenote Note,db_jobordernote JNote, corporateuser User where 
Note.noteid=JNote.noteid
and Note.commentingPersonID = User.userid 
and User.firstName='Avishek'
and Note.action='Sourcing') CANDYS
where P.candidateID= CANDYS.candidateId
and P.joborderid=CANDYS.jobOrderID
and P.dateadded between '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-30'
```

This is my query .So this query will give each section result.Now if any of the query don't have data it should not be blank instead it will show 0 in the place of result.how to do that.somebody please help.

[image]

like the image it is showing 2 rows.also not sure which row data it is showing.

Comment: In Oracle, there is a 'distinct' applied to unions like that by default... not sure how MySQL works but you could try changing your "union" to "union all", that would fix it in Oracle.

Comment: Yeah, just checked the MySQL docs, the behaviour is the same as Oracle and "union all" will give you what you want.

Comment: might need to apply isnull(blahblah,0) if necessary, certainly with outer joins

Answer (score 0):

To simplify problem, let's suppose this schema:

```
create table t ( i int, a char(1) );
insert into t values ( 1, 'a');
```

In this case, when the row is not included in `where` clause we want an extra fictitious row with `zero` as data. We can accomplish this with vars:

```
SET @f=0;
select i,a, @f:=1
from t
where i<>1                     --< row not included
union
select 0,'0', @f as f          --< fictitious row,only if f=0
from ( select 1 ) tt
having f=0                     --< f is 0
```

Results:

```
i     a
0     '0'
```

When a row is included:

```
SET @f=0;
select i,a, @f:=1
from t
where i=1                     --< row is included
union
select 0,'0', @f as f
from ( select 1 ) tt
having f=0                     --< f is 1
```

Results:

```
i     a
1     'a'
```

From this snipped you can inferring changes needed in your code. Used to simplify problem to simplify help. **Learn about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**